# Explain that F is primitive for f and calculate integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a following task, I need to explain that $f(z)=z\cdot \sin z$ has primitive $F(z)=-z\cdot \cos z + \sin z$ and calculate integral:
$$I = \int_{A}f(z)dz$$ where $A=\{z\in C: |z|=\pi/2, Im z > 0$}. 
So if I show that $F(z)$ is in fact primitive, my integral is just $I=F(-\pi/2)-F(\pi/2)$. To explain that it's in fact primitive I should show it's holomorphic on set containing A and $F'=f$? Could you lend me a hand here, as I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Why not just differentiate $F?$

Comment: That's suffice? I have absolutly no intuition in complex analisis. Thanks;